# VBScript type mismatch when indexing into a Byte() variable

Tags: vbscript, byte

Code:

```vb
Set UTF8 = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
x = UTF8.GetBytes_4("hello")
WScript.Echo TypeName(x)
WScript.Echo x(1)
```

Error:

```
C:\>cscript foo.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Byte()
foo.vbs(4, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'x'
```

What is the problem here? How can I fix this code?

Comment: `GetBytes` won't return a VBScript (COM) array. and you can't use CLR object's indexed properties from VBScript, you need to use the `Item` property instead. Try `WScript.Echo x.Item(1)`.

Comment: As a Byte() is not an object, using .Item() is a bad idea.

Comment: @Dai Wrong. COM Interop takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MidB() to access the elements of a Byte():

```
>> Set UTF8 = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
>> x = UTF8.GetBytes_4("hello")
>> For y = 1 To 1 + UBound(x)
>>     z = MidB(x, y, 1)
>>     WScript.Echo TypeName(z), z
>> Next
>> z = x.Item(1)
>>
String h
String e
String l
String l
String o
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Objekt erforderlich
>>
```

As a Byte() is not an object, using .Item() is a bad idea.